# unsetting the background to palette

Tags: background, tcl, tk-toolkit, color-scheme

I'm having trouble using Tcl/Tk with both the default palette colors and custom colors.

I have a text-pane, that I would like to set the background color under specific circumstances (e.g. to indicate missing user input), and then fall back to the default background color (once the specific circumstances have been resolved).

So far I've been using the `-background` option to widgets.
E.g.

```
$ wish
# ALERT: turn the background to pink
. configure -background pink
# SNAFU: turn the background back to white
. configure -background white
```

However, I just discovered [`tk_setPalette`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/palette.htm), which allows me to set the global palette of my application.
Unfortunatly the two seem to not go together very well: once i've explicitely set the background color of a widget, there seems to be no way to *unset* it (and fall back to the default color as currently set by the palette):

```
$ wish
# cheesy color-scheme
tk_setPalette brown
# ALERT: turn the background to pink
. configure -background pink
# SNAFU: turn the background back to "normal"
. configure -background white
# hmpf, no not "white"; the current palette is 'brown'
. configure -background brown
```

One solution (which I would like to avoid) is to store the palette in a variable, and use that to explicitely set the background:

```
$ wish
# cheesy color-scheme
set mypalette brown
tk_setPalette $mypalette
# ALERT: turn the background to pink
. configure -background pink
# SNAFU: turn the background back to "normal"
. configure -background $mypalette
```

However, this has various drawbacks:
- i would need to keep track of any palette change that happens in my application (this is potentially hard to do, as my application has a "plugin" system that can be used for skinning)
- this only works for the `background`, but setting a color-palette changes more colors than just the background.

Esp. the 2nd drawback is a real issue.
Currently one of my widgets is a text `entry`, which uses `white` as the default background, `pink` as the alert-color and the `default` text color.
Whenever I change the color-scheme to anything but `white`, the default text-color will become `white`, thus making the text invisible (since the background is `white` as well, rather than `default`).

So the questions are:

- How can I restore a color to the defaults provided by a `palette`?
- How can i query the default color for a given element from a `palette`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think tk_setPalette is supported any more.  It is used 
in conjuction with the pre-ttk widgets and will not work with all
themes.

Querying the default colors:

To get the background color of a ttk widget:

```
 set bg [ttk::style lookup TFrame -background]
```

where TFrame is the "class" of the widget.

To get the background color of a pre-ttk widget:

```
 set bg [. cget -background]
```

This method will work with virtually any pre-ttk widget.

As for tracking the color changes, I would save any palette base color,
background, fieldbackground, foreground and other colors you might potentially need when
the theming plugins is loaded.

Your other choice is to save the individual widget's current foreground / background, etc.
before you modify it for error display.

```
 set oldbg [.myentry cget -background]
 set oldfg [.myentry cget -foreground]
 ... change colors, display error condition...
 ... when error is resolved ...
 .myentry configure -background $oldbg
 .myentry configure -foreground $oldfg
```

References: [ttk::style](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_style.htm) [frame](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/frame.htm) [tk_setPalette](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/palette.htm)